# How to bake a plugin controller without scaffolding in cakephp 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, code-generation, cakephp-2.3

When I bake my plugin controller, it always generate with scaffolding.

```
class MyController extends PluginAppController {

/**
 * Scaffold
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
        public $scaffold;

}
```

Anyone help me to bake plugin without scaffolding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your main app directory in the command line enter

1. `cake bake controller -p <pluginname>`
2. select the controller you're baking
3. Answer the scaffolding question with default (no)

   Would you like to use dynamic scaffolding? (y/n)
   [n] >

Comment: Just to add, be sure that the model in the plugin has been baked first.

Comment: Thanks. my mistake was I write the command as "cake bake controller MyControlleName --plugin MyPluginNane". By this way it was always bake with scafold. If I do not put the controller name, then I get the option like this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mk97 please go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374636/how-to-create-cakephp-2-plugin-using-cake-bake-all-command

Comment: @faiyaz alam please check my reply in that question. You're not using the answer that is provided above.