# How to create cakephp 2 plugin using cake bake all command?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, console

I have tried following codes in sequence to create my plugin:

```
cake bake model all -p MyPlugin  // working 

cake bake controller all -p MyPlugin // not working
No controllers were baked, Model need to exist before Controller can be baked.


cake bake view all -p MyPlugin // not working
No error and no views are created.
```

How can I resolve this?

I am using cakephp 2.6 and there are four tables posts,categories,tags, posts_tags.

Comment: Faiyaz, you tagged me in another question... and that question has an answer. Why are you using "all" in your bake commands? it should simply be, as answered in other question `cake bake controller -p <plugin name>`

Comment: @mk97. Thanks for your reply.  I am using 'all' because I want to bake the plugin with all the possible models or controllers or views at once. I will check your answer one more time carefully and then let you know about it.